# Give a few seconds of delay to play a background music

Tags: php, html, embed, delay

I want to combine the PHP with HTML to give a few seconds of delay to play the background music, but I don't know how to use delay function in PHP to do that with embed tag in HTML5.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please. Don't play background music.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to do it in php, your actual page must have the extension of php as my_page.php
then you can use an if statement(if you think you need to)
and say `header("Refresh=4; url=http://www.yourdomain.com");`
this will wait 4 seconds and then it will take the page to the url that you defined.
if you wanna keep the page longer, just increase the value of refresh.
other than that you can use javascript as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. most people hate background music.
2. You can do this :

   setTimeout( function() { YOUR_CODE } , TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS );

for more information please see this page : [Window setTimeout() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: I know most people hate it , but this is an exception.
thank you for your good help
I'm going to work on it